# Sublime Text 2: can't create symlink to subl, says "bin/subl: No such file or directory"

Tags: sublimetext2

I've downloaded and installed Sublime text 2. I am following the directions here:  but I am stuck at this part:

*The first task is to make a symlink to subl. Assuming you've placed Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, and that you have a ~/bin directory in your path, you can run:*

ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text " ~/bin/subl

However, when I do this it tells me /Users/User/bin/subl: No such file or directory.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Here are another instructions for this matter: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/

Answer (score 54):

I'd recommend adding it to your local bin:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Edit: Make sure your local bin directory exists before running this command:

```
mkdir /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I've got "ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory"

Comment: @onmyway133 does your bin directory exist?

Comment: This worked for me but had to run as `sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I don't fully understand why yet, but I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4194/302720) useful in explaining some context

Answer (score 24):

I add my sym links to /usr/local/bin, for Sublime Text 3 I set mine up like so:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Then you can open up the current directory list using:

```
subl .
```

If you find subl abbreviation annoying as some people I know seem to do, then change it to 'sublime'

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

And call it using:

```
sublime .
```

Comment: I followed this entire procedure, but `subl .` results in: `-bash: subl: command not found`

Comment: `ln: /usr/local/bin/: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, you can run this:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl
```

Note: The above snippet puts the symlink in `/bin/subl` rather than `~/bin/subl`.

Comment: what's the difference between adding a tilde? (~)

Comment: @ayjay the tilde references your home directory. So /bin/subl starts at the root of your system, while ~/bin/subl starts at your home directory - it's a shortcut for the directory (on a Mac) /Users/<yourusername>

Answer (score 7):

**and that you have a ~/bin directory in your path**

First, you need that directory for the `ln` command to work, and eventually, it will need to be in your path to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

To make the directory:

`mkdir ~/bin`

Adding it to your execution path is trickier, but there are plenty of resources available.

Comment: This was my issue here.

Answer (score 3):

Following Simon's example above, For Sublime Text 3, here is what worked for me:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Please note, to install (on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6)  in /usr/local/bin sudo was required.

Comment: This is confirmed working with ST3 and OS X 10.15.3 - with sudo and `/usr/local/bin/subl`

Answer (score 2):

### Info

- **OS: Mac OSX High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65)**
- **Sublime Version: Version 3.1.1 Build 3176**

I took the command from [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html) website

### Got An Error

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln: /Users/jkirchoff/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

### Did Some Checking

Just to make sure the path exists.

> NOTE: the `"`'s allow the space in the path.

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
ln: ./subl: File exists
```

### Compared Note from this page

What @NotSimon wrote on this page, Then Ran:

```
ln -s "/usr/local/bin/subl"
ln: ./subl: File exists
```

and then followed the rest.

### The Complete Line that worked for me:

> ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl

### Success

Now I can run `subl` as a command in Terminal!

This command opens the directory as a "Project" in SublimeText.

```
subl ~/Desktop
```

### Optional

> I followed the [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html) recommendation & added this to my 
>  `~/.bash_profile`.

The command works without it, just following guidelines.

> `echo "export EDITOR='subl -w'" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove tilde `~` from `~/bin/subl`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mac terminal, 
just replace "Sublime Text 2.app" 
with "Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/" anywhere within the command.

That should do it.